# What is aws redhat root password

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rhel

I am new in aws, i lunch an redhat instance on aws with free-tier, i logged with ssh client.

My ip starts with like this `ec2-user@ec.....bla.com`

that is mean i logged with `ec2-user`, when i try to run some service inside the instance machine, It ask me for root password.

Can anyone tell me what is the root password? i couldn't figure out this yet

Here you go to see some example:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172--my-aws-ip---34 ~]$ systemctl start docker.service
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ====
Authentication is required to start 'docker.service'.
Authenticating as: root
Password:
```

Comment: using `sudo su -` to swtich to root and execute above command or use `sudo` to execute command.

Comment: Thanks, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `sudo su -` to swtich to root and execute above command or execute as `sudo systemctl start docker.service`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend sudo su - unless absolutely neccessary. Better to use sudo systemctl ....